# What does a successful CTS testing look like

Tags: android, cts

Im sorry if this question is to much of a beginer question, if you know of a place where I would be able to have easier questions regarding CTS answered I would happily ask there.

I have been running CTS on a device, and it came back with 7,000 tests failed, and a few that were not executed.

Figuring that this was because the project has not been completed as of yet, we benchmarked using a Nexus 6, where we had over 17k test fail and several thousand not executed.

Is this customary?  Or is a successful CTS run supposed to have ALL tests performed and passed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe it's possible to get a waiver in certain circumstances, particularly when a test is believed to be incorrect, but the tests are generally expected to pass.  Are there specific categories that are failing or being skipped?

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for your response. We had some tests that failed, and some that were not executed at all.  We could understand our device in development failing, but on the Nexus 6, we had the following test not even execute:  android.os.cts.AbiTest -- testNo64 
notExecuted  And we had this test fail :       android.hardware.camera2.cts.RecordingTest 
-- testSupportedVideoSizes 
fail
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session has been closed; further changes are illegal.
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.

Comment: mind you, this is on top of several other fails and not executed tests.  We thought we may be performing the test incorrectly as this was a nexus 6 that we were trying to determine a GOOD test vs a Bad test, apparently they are no good, either way lol.  Any Suggestions?

Comment: You'd need to dig into the code (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/lollipop-release/tests/tests/hardware/src/android/hardware/camera2/cts/RecordingTest.java), exception stack trace, and logcat output to figure out what exactly is going wrong. It's fairly likely that whatever is causing one test to fail is also causing many others to fail. You can run small subsets of CTS with the cts-tradefed command -- use this to focus on a single failing test.

Comment: Awesome, this is the most help Ive gotten, I truly, and deeply appreciate it.  Just to verify, the command Id be throwing in to isolate the failing tests would be:  cts­tradefed run cts ­­--plan <plan_name> , where the plan name is the test package that failed i.e.: android.media ABI: armeabi-v7a

Comment: You should be able to narrow it down to a specific class name, but I don't remember the command syntax (maybe add `--test <test-name>`?)  Mostly you just want to be able to examine the failure without seeing lots of stuff from other tests.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't set-up your device first.

For instance,

- if you have a SD card slot, you have to insert one
- You have to connect to Wifi network
- You have to remove lock pattern
- If there's a SIM card slot, you have to insert one
- ...

Please have a look at this document:
http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/fr//compatibility/android-cts-manual.pdf
At paragraph 3.3

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately we followed the CTS Manual to the letter, and set up both devices exactly as requested.  Could you confirm that the nexus 6 should have passed ALL the tests?  Is that what a successful CTS run looks like?  Is there any reason some of the tests should fail or not be executed?